# ENOENT when I try to write to external storage

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception, android-external-storage, saving-data

I'm trying to create a video app on external storage

```
 File pathToExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 //to this path add a new directory path and create new App dir (InstroList) in /documents Dir
 File appDirectory = new File(pathToExternalStorage.getAbsolutePath()  + "/documentst");
 appDirectory.mkdirs();
 mMuxer = new MediaMuxer(appDirectory.getAbsolutePath()+ "/video2.mp4", MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
```

I'm getting this error

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/1DEB-2B0B/documentst/video2.mp4: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

When I create the directory myself it throws permissions denied error.
I've added the permissions to manifest xml file and I'm sure that sdcard is mounted.

I'm working with android studio and a standard emulator.

Comment: Since the error was raised from the MediaMuxer call I assume mkdirs() returned without exception. Was the directory created or did mkdirs() silently fail without creating the directory?

Comment: Also, you said you added the permissions (which ones? WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is the only one that seems relevant to me), but perhaps it would help if you included a snippet of the manifest.

Comment: Which android version ? I think you could not write because you don't have permissions on device, is not the same with permissions in Manifest. Have you tried write/create in public storage? Something like: `File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).
                getAbsoluteFile() + "/MyFolder");` finally, I recommend test with `if(file.exists){if(file.mkdirs(){doSomething}}`